# Правописание НЕ

Tags: слитно-раздельно, частица-не

Это было наихудшее, что могло случиться: они погибали, а вся их огневая мощь оставалась вовсе (НЕ)ИСПОЛЬЗОВАННОЙ.

ИСПОЛЬЗОВАННОЙ - признак предмета по действию, отвечает на вопрос "мощь какая?", изменяемое слово. Точно причастие. Имеет при себе зависимое слово вовсе - наречие. Его можно заменить словом полностью, а значит это наречие меры, степени. Пишется слитно, а оказывается - нет. Что неправильно?

> Я похоже вопрос неправильно задал. Только сейчас понял: оставалась
>   какой? - признак действия, а значит является наречием. Но оно
>   изменяемое:  их огневые мощи остались вовсе не использованы. А наречие
>   неизменяемая часть речи... может быть это прилагательное, но с наличием наречия меры, степени, а значит пишется слитно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче так. Опускаю пока свой вопрос о первоисточнике.

Посмотрел везде, где мог, "использованный" вежде считается прилагательным. Если это не указано явно, может быть указана краткая форма с одним Н (словарь РАН п/р Лопанина), что невозможно для причастия.

Таким образом раздельное написание вполне обоснованно.

> Частица "не" пишется раздельно: .... б) если не входит в состав
>   усилительных отрицаний далеко не, отнюдь не, вовсе не, ничуть не,
>   нисколько не и т.п., предшествующих существительному, прилагательному
>   или наречию, например: он вовсе не приятель нам, далеко не
>   единственное желание, отнюдь не справедливое решение, нисколько не
>   лучший выход, далеко не достаточно.

Что же касается ваших соображений про то, почему это причастие, то могу только одно сказать. Не знаю, как сейчас в школе учат, но с точки зрения академической науки критерием является только наличие значения признака качества (прилагательное) или состояния (причастия). В слове "израсходованный" значение качественного признака более существенно (например то, что это качество уже не изменится во времени). Видимо, ваши соображения об отнесении "израсходованный" к причастиям базировались на неверное посылке.

У автора - по-другому

> Это было наихудшее, что могло случиться, - они погибали, а вся их
>   огневая мощь оставалась почти неиспользованной

(Василь Быков, "Сотников")
http://www.kniga.com/books/preview_txt.asp?sku=ebooks352827#TOC_IDADI1EE

Вот и первоисточник нашел.
https://infourok.ru/podgotovka-k-ege-po-russkomu-yaziku-1878318-page2.html

Ну это не поддается критике. Весьма сомнительный прием - заменить у автора одно слово ради того, чтобы запутать учащихся. Пользуйтесь только проверенными пособиями.

И еще. Пользоваться подобным приемом (заменой слова) даже на синонимичное, не говоря уж о весьма далеком, допустимо тогда и только тогда, когда это прямо оговорено в правилах. Иначе могут возникнуть недоразумения подобные тому, с которым мы столкнулись. Слово "почти" допускает слитное написание не с последующим прилагательным, поскольку "почти не" не является усилительным отрицанием.

Answer (score 0):

Это было наихудшее, что могло случиться, – они погибали, а вся их огневая мощь оставалась **почти неиспользованной** (так у автора?).

При замене наречия ПОЧТИ наречием ВОВСЕ **возможны обе формы написания НЕ**.
Наречие ВОВСЕ **может усиливать  и утверждение** (слитное написание НЕ), и **отрицание** (раздельное написание НЕ):  **"вовсе неиспользованной и вовсе не использованной".**

Розенталь [§ 57. Частица не с прилагательными](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77)

Двоякое толкование допускает и наречие вовсе; ср.: Приводились **вовсе не убедительные** доводы (‘отнюдь’). — Авторами этих работ являются менее популярные или **вовсе неизвестные** авторы (‘совсем, совершенно’ — в разговорном стиле речи).

Comment: Я написал так, как было у автора. Это задание из ЕГЭ и там необходим только один ответ (ДА/НЕТ). Очень странно...

Comment: @Шрдтьдлер это реальное ЕГЭ или неизвестно кем состряпанное пособие по подготовке к нему? Последние изобилуют неточностями и недоразумениями, не говоря уж о просто ошибках. Но здесь речь не об этом.

Comment: @Sibylla замена "совсем" на "почти" не является эквивалентной. "Почти не" не является усилительным отрицанием, о которых говорится в § 89.Правил-56: *Частица "не" пишется раздельно: .... б) если "не" входит в состав усилительных отрицаний далеко не, отнюдь не, вовсе не, ничуть не, нисколько не и т.п.*

Comment: @Мимоходов "ЕГЭ 1000 заданий по русскому языку" Г.Т. Егораева. Буду на "решу егэ" теперь решать.